# Test Flash iOS app in Device Central

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to test my Air 3.0 application for iOS in Flash Professional CS5.5.

But since I use the Air 3.0 SDK I can't open my file in the Device Central and opening the file with the normal Flash Player will not track the touch events.

Any ideas how to test an application for ios on a desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate some of the touch interactions by using a touchpad (like on a laptop) that supports multiple touches, but this will only give you certain things.

Unfortunately you can't really fully test an iOS AIR application without using a device.